# Regex to get first X characters of a string cut to closest word

Tags: regex, string

I'm trying to put together a regex which will match the first 100 characters of a string without cutting off words, but guaranteeing that I will never exceed 100 characters:

`/^(.{0,100}[^\s]*)/`

The problem is that this cuts off after the last word if it bleeds over, rather than before. I'm looking to cut before - so if I take 10 characters as an example, this will cut at:

`The quick brown`

when I want it to cut at:

`The quick`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Try this regex using Negative Lookahead:

```
/^(.{0,100}(?!\w))/
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/5BPqk5/2

Comment: Thanks, but this does not achieve the desired effect - it cuts halfway through the word. So it essentially gives me: `The big bro` instead of `The big` if my sentence is `The big brown fox`

Comment: I tried it there too. I think it's because the example  'The quick brown fox' cuts off at a word naturally at 10 characters. Try 'The big brown fox' instead, or change the character count to 12.

Comment: @Phoenix20 I updated my answer. Try Negative Lookahead in Regex.