# I like to cut my images' IPTC core Title to a certain number

Tags: exiftool

I like to cut my images' IPTC core Title, Description, Headline characters at to a certain number.

So for example if an image has 300 characters, I would like to cut it at 195 characters to be 195 character long.

It would be great if it would cut it at the nearest word, resulting a title below 195 character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To cut to a specific length, you could use this command:
`exiftool -if "length($Title)>195" "-Title<${Title;s/^(.{1,195}).*/$1/s}" /path/to/files/`

Cutting on a word, based upon [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41732868/3525475), would be:
`exiftool -if "length($Title)>195" "-Title<${Title;s/^(.{1,195}(?!\w)).*/$1/s}" /path/to/files/`

This command creates backup files.  Add [`-overwrite_original`](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#overwrite_original) to suppress the creation of backup files.  Add [`-r`](https://ExifTool.org/exiftool_pod.html#r-.--recurse) to recurse into subdirectories.  If this command is run under Unix/Mac, reverse any double/single quotes to avoid bash interpretation.

Comment: Thank you! However it leaves documents with 197-199 characters.

"It would be great if it would cut it at the nearest word, resulting a title below 195 character"

Comment: Can you list what a few words on both sides of where the cut is?  It should cut to a max of 195 no matter what.  Also, are there any characters used that might only be expressed in Unicode?  Those would require more than 1 byte per character, but still only be counted as 1 character.

Comment: I just realized the command left the titles they were. I didn't shortened them

Comment: Aha. The problem is I need to cut IPTC core Title, Headline and description too

Comment: The problem is solved, because my software only takes the Title in account.

Comment: Hello! Somehow I would need to cut IPTC core Title, Description and Headline fields.
The program I used has changed the way it works. ... I must cut all 3 to maximum 195 character long with cut at a word end